# Swift - Local images load at least 10 seconds after the ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

It's been 2 months since I started learning IOS Development. I am creating an app that will require a login view at first. So,

1. I use HTTP get method -Asynchronously- to check login info and get a Json response.
2. I started understanding using the delegate/protocol way. I think I am doing everything correct about delegation.
3. In my LoginViewController(1st) I check the returned data from GET request. My data arrives.
   4.When everything is correct I save userdata to UserDefaults and perform a segue.

So My Issue is;
 When the SecondViewController is loaded, every element that should be seen in the view is there, Except the stupid images (completely static, not being added or edited programatically). They load 10 or 20 seconds after the view load is finished. Query is definitely finished because the 2nd VC shows the data correctly as soon as in loads.

I noticed that this problem occurs when I fetch data asynchronously only.

I tried synchronous get method. The images load as soon as the view appears.

What am I missing? Thanks for any idea.

Here is my code:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, ConnectionDelegate {

var connectionModel:ConnectionModel = ConnectionModel()
var userDefaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults()

@IBOutlet weak var codeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var failedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rememberSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var loading: UIActivityIndicatorView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.connectionModel.delegate = self

    if(self.userDefaults.remember()){
        self.loading.startAnimating()
        self.connectionModel.fetchBasicData()
    }
}

func resultCame(value: Int) {
    self.loading.stopAnimating()

    switch value {
    case 1:
        loginToMain()
    case 2:
        noStudent()
    case 3:
        serverFailed()
    case 0:
        connectionFailed()
    default:
        connectionFailed()
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.loading.startAnimating()
    self.connectionModel.checkLogin(usernameField.text, password: passwordField.text, code:codeField.text)
}

func loginToMain(){
    if(self.rememberSwitch.on){
        self.userDefaults.rememberUser()
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToMain", sender: self)
}

func noStudent(){
    self.failedLabel.text = "Giriş bilgileri bulunamadı."
}

func serverFailed(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sunucu Hatası", message: "Hata Kodu: 0x03", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Kapat", style: .Default) { (action) in
        self.connectionModel.checkConn(self)
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: false, completion:nil)
}

func connectionFailed(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Bağlantı Hatası", message: "Hata Kodu: 0x00", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Kapat", style: .Default) { (action) in
        self.connectionModel.checkConn(self)
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: falfalse, completion:nil)
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ok I think I figured it out now after trying 60billion different test scenarios. The images were not loading in the second VC; because even after my data arrived from the async request in the first VC and the segue is performed as a result, the request did not end in the background for another 20seconds. As soon the request was finished (for who knows why) the images load.

Why does the request keep being active and connected even after the completion handler is run? I doesn't make any sense!??

**SOLVED:**
No one told me to use this f.ing function inside the completion handler. Apperently, that was the reason for images loading this late. Grrrr...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.loading.stopAnimating()
    self.label.text = "string coming from data"
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say as we can see the completion handler which seems to be in  ConnectionModel

Comment: Thanks the Tom. I just learned that I had to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) inside the comp handler. Simple piece of code gave me painful headaches for 2 days. Whatever! I am OK now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are being downloaded then when download them asynchronously, the rest of the UI will load and the images will load only when they have finished downloading (so that time depends on your connection speed).

However if your images are being downloaded synchronously then the app will wait until they are downloaded to refresh the UI, that's why everything appears at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my images are not remote images. They are inside the app bundle.

Comment: Where do you call your images to be updated ? Can you show more code ? My guess is that the call is made in the completion handler of you request that is why they won't display

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out now after trying 60billion different test scenarios.

The images were not loading in the second VC; because even after my data arrived from the async request in the first VC and the segue is performed as a result, the request did not end in the background for another 20seconds. As soon the request was finished (for who knows why) the images load. Why does the request keep being active and connected even after the completion handler is run? I doesn't make any sense.